# О трех буквах "е"

Tags: словарь

Жираф - животное длиннош**еее**
Есть ли в русском языке другие слова с тремя "е" подряд?

Comment: "Дорогой Андерсен, напишите нам сказку **помалофеее**!" - "Это как же, господин редактор??" - "А чтобы *фей поменьше* было..."

Answer (score 1):

А что, короткошеее шеей не вышло?
Змееед еще.

Comment: А разве не змееяд?

Comment: Не "разве", а "или". Или "И" - кто как понимает.