# Слова с тремя Е

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов, графика

Прочитала, что в русском языке существует не одно, а два слова с тремя Е подряд. Одно общеизвестно: "длинношеее". А вот какое второе?

Comment: Любые слова с "шеее" ( "кривошеее", "широкошеее", "короткошеее" и прочие) не считаются по отдельности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Змееед (орел-змееед). Но и с "шеей" не одно слово, есть еще "короткошеее", "кривошеее"...

Comment: Клееед  - тот, кто *клей* ест.

Comment: Орел - он змееяд правильно называется.

Answer (score 0):

Повтор.
[О трех буквах "е"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/22985)

Comment: На всякий случай продублирую ссылку на этом сайте: http://rus.stackexchange.com/q/22985/176629